# Efficient Algorithm for Combinations With Replacement (n choose k)

Tags: combinatorics

I am looking for the canonical implementation of the "k-combinations with repetition" algorithm.

Simple Example:

Input: "ABC" (choose 2)

> ['AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'BB', 'BC', 'CC']

I have a recursive implementation, I'm looking for the performance optimized state of the art version.  Usually people mention Knuth for this, but I haven't seen a specific reference to Vol 4a or otherwise for this particular one.  Not to say it isn't there, just haven't found any references to it.

Where might I look further into this?

Comment: Consult Section 7 of Knuth's Art of Computer Programming. See for example [this](http://www.kcats.org/csci/464/doc/knuth/fascicles/fasc3a.pdf) (other parts are in the same directory).